# Can a Wildshaped druid ride a mount?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, mounted-combat, mount

The only requirements I know of indicate the creature must be at least one size category larger and "have an anatomy that could serve as a mount."

By RAW, a Black Bear could theoretically ride on an Elephant then, yes?

Comment: You've missed the most dangerous animal in the world: [a shark riding on an elephant's back, just trampling and eating everything they see.](https://www.nbc.com/saturday-night-live/video/deep-thoughts-shark-riding-an-elephant/n10016?snl=1)

Comment: [Related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45488/the-stackomounts) (and amusing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes

Providing that the mount can serve as a mount and the rider can be a rider (e.g. snakes might require some special tack to be either a mount or a rider) that is the only criteria.

An army of pixies mounted on halflings mounted on humans mounted on horses mounted on elephants mounted on dragons is a frightening thing to have bearing down on you.

Comment: If I have an army of dragons bearing down on me, I am not sure that I will care whether there is anything riding the dragons.

Comment: You forgot the tarasques that the dragons are riding. (Is that the plural for tarasque?)