# What racial features can a Kalashtar use while wildshaped?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, racial-traits

As the title states, I want to know which racial features, if any, of the [kalashtar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/kalashtar) are usable in wildshaped form.

The traits are named as follows: Dual Mind, Mental Discipline, Mind Link, Severed from Dreams

Both of these questions are related:
[How do I determine if a Racial Trait applies to Wildshape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108561/45088)
[Does a wildshaped druid retain his/her racial resistances?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138169/45088)

This was a question I thought of when looking at this question, as a way of communicating to the Bestial Spirit: [Is it possible to combine Summon Beastial Spirit spell and Wildshape to travel by air?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170405/45088)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Kalashtar features come from a spiritual link; Wild Shape does *not* sever this link

The Wild Shape feature states:

> [...] You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing so. [...]

So we only need to know whether a given new form is physically capable of using Kalashtar features so let's look at where those are from:

> [...] The kalashtar are a compound people, created from the union of humanity and renegade spirits from the plane of dreams—spirits called quori [...]
>
> [...] Every kalashtar has a connection to a spirit of light, a bond shared by other members of their bloodline. Kalashtar appear human, but their spiritual connection affects them in a variety of ways. [...]

Nothing in the description of the Kalashtar gives conditions for this spiritual link to end, thus we can conclude that Wild Shape does not end this link and so Wild Shape does not stop the Kalashtar from benefitting from all these features.

---

Wild Shape also states:

> [...] you retain your alignment, personality, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores. [...]

All of these things (as well as skill proficiencies and [perhaps languages](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71106)) are various aspects of the PC's knowledge and mentality and they are maintained during Wild Shape. Similarly, it would make sense to me if a spiritual link to your own mind were maintained during Wild Shape.

Answer (score 1):

## All four of the racial features mentioned are usable while in a Wild Shape form

The pertinent part of the Wild Shape feature description for this question is as follows, which is part of one of its bullet points.

> You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing so.

As NautArch discusses in [How do I determine if a Racial Trait applies to Wildshape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108561/45088), the only limiting factor for a racial feature to not be used while in a Wild Shape form is a lack of anatomy. I also discuss this topic in [Does a wildshaped druid retain his/her racial resistances?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138169/45088), when talking about resistances of a tiefling and whether they are carried over into a Wild Shape form. In both questions, the highest voted answer states that a racial feature is only disallowed use if the feature specifically requires some anatomy that the new form doesn't have.

All four of the racial features mentioned mention no particular anatomy required for their use, therefore they are all usable while transformed. This can be seen in the snippets below. An example of anatomy required would be requiring two heads for Dual Mind or some kind of magical horn for Mind Link.

> Dual Mind. You have advantage on all Wisdom saving throws.
>
> Mental Discipline. You have resistance to psychic damage.
>
> Mind Link. You can speak telepathically to any creature you can see, [..]
>
> Severed from Dreams. Kalashtar sleep, but they don't connect to the plane of dreams as other creatures do. [..] As such, you are immune to spells and other magical effects that require you to dream, [..]

Comment: Other racial feature make no direct mention of anatomy either. E.g. dwarven resilience does not say that it is derived from your blood composition or immune system, yet it is doubtful that it would work when you have a different body. A dragonborn's breath weapon does not say that you need a special gland to produce it. And so on.

Comment: @Szega And thus those features would be permitted to be used while wildshaped.

Comment: I disagree. I do not think "no explicit mention" is enough justification.

Comment: It would be good to quote the important passage from Wild Shape: "You retain the benefit of any features from your class, race, or other source and can use them if the new form is physically capable of doing so." That reduces the question to whether the new form can be considered physically capable of using the features in question (which I'm still not sure of, but at least it's a fairly objective question).

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson thank you for the suggestion; I've expanded the question to address that.